debsig: No applicable policy found when running debsig-verify
Background
I am building a Debian package (foo is the name for the purpose of the question). I want to sign the package with GPG. In this example below, I changed the names, version number, email, etc. with fictional ones.
I created a Github Repo to reproduce my problem in a docker container to make it easier to get help. Just run run.sh which will create an image, run the script in a container then remove the container.
Folder Structure
My package folder structure looks like this:
foo-1.2.3-4_amd64
  DEBIAN
    control
    postinst
    prerm
  lib
    systemd
      system
        foo.service
  opt
    my-company
      foo
        bin
          foo-binary
        conf
          foo-config.yml

Building the package
I am using the following command to build the package
dpkg-deb --root-owner-group --build ./foo-1.2.3-4_amd64 ./foo-1.2.3-4_amd64.deb

The OS I am using is Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (Running on WSL on Windows 11). The dpkg-deb version I use is: Debian 'dpkg-deb' package archive backend version 1.22.6 (amd64). The above command runs fine, and when I test the installing and uninstall the package, everything runs as expected.
Signing the package
Now I want to sign the package using a GPG key. So I run the following script
#obtain the GPG key ID
KEYID=$(gpg --list-keys info@example.com | sed -n '2p' | cut -c31-)

# Sign the package
debsigs --sign=origin -k "${KEYID}" foo-1.2.3-4_amd64.deb

This is where I get the first problem. I get the following output
 *** Processing file foo-1.2.3-4_amd64.deb
Use of uninitialized value $args[4] in exec at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/debsigs/forktools.pm line 64.
Use of uninitialized value $args[5] in exec at /usr/share/perl5/Debian/debsigs/forktools.pm line 64.
RUNNING: gpg --openpgp --detach-sign --default-key XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX at /usr/bin/debsigs line 117.
no entry  in archive
no entry  in archive
gpg: using "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" as default secret key for signing

So the above "no entry  in archine" and "Use of uninitialized value" seem to be warnings, so I am thinking may be I can ignore them???
debsigs version is: 0.01.19
Verifying the package
Anyway, after I sign the package (and getting the warnings shown above), I try to verify the package.
# Add the key
KEY_DIR=/usr/share/debsig/keyrings/${KEYID}
sudo mkdir "${KEY_DIR}"
gpg --export "$KEYID" | sudo tee "${KEY_DIR}/debsig.gpg" > /dev/null

# create policy file
POL_DIR="/etc/debsig/policies/${KEYID}"
sudo mkdir "${POL_DIR}"
cat << EOT | sudo tee "${POL_DIR}/test.pol" > /dev/null
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE Policy SYSTEM "http://www.debian.org/debsig/1.0/policy.dtd">
<Policy xmlns="http://www.debian.org/debsig/1.0/">
  <Origin Name="Test" id="${KEYID}" Description="Test &lt;info@example.com&gt;"/>
  <Selection>
    <Required Type="origin" File="debsig.gpg" id="${KEYID}"/>
  </Selection>
  <Verification MinOptional="0">
    <Required Type="origin" File="debsig.gpg" id="${KEYID}"/>
  </Verification>
</Policy>
EOT

# Verify the package
debsig-verify --debug --verbose "foo-1.2.3-4_amd64.deb"

debsig-verify command results in the following output:
debsig: Starting verification for: foo-1.2.3-4_amd64.deb
debsig: Using policy directory: /etc/debsig/policies/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
debsig:   Parsing policy file: /etc/debsig/policies/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/test.pol
debsig: No applicable policy found.

When running debsig-verify --version I get
Debsig Program Version - 0.29
  Signature Version - 1.0
  Signature Namespace - https://www.debian.org/debsig/1.0/
  Policies Directory - /etc/debsig/policies
  Keyrings Directory - /usr/share/debsig/keyrings

Summary
So I have two problems:
First the warning I get when signing the package. I don't know how to fix, or whether I can ignore it or not.
Second, the package verification fails with No applicable policy found.
How can I fix those problems?
